# Can "C056_CompositeRaceorEthnicityInformation" record repeat in an 834

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013

I am creating an outbound 834 in BizTalk 2013 R2. A map is being used to convert to the 834 format. 
I am having an issue in one of the nodes called C056_CompositeRaceorEthnicityInformation which is in the 2100A and 2100B loops. If I look at the properties of this node it says Max Occurs = 10. However if I have more than one records of C056_CompositeRaceorEthnicityInformation being created in the outbound, it gives the following error in the edi send pipeline:

> Unable to read the stream produced by the pipeline. 
>    Details: Error: 1 (Field level error)
>       SegmentID: DMG
>       Position in TS: 18
>       Data Element ID: C056_CompositeRaceorEthnicityInformation
>       Position in Segment: 5
>       Data Value: 
>       3: Node cannot repeat*

In order to avoid this error and get the outbound generated I may have to limit the repetition of this node to 1 in my outbound. But I was wondering what is causing this error in the EDI send pipeline? I tried passing an 834 with multiple of C056_CompositeRaceorEthnicityInformation through a receive port for which the EDI receive pipeline has no problems in accepting it, however when I route it through a send port I get the same error. Also if I do a validate instance for the 834 (with multiple C056_CompositeRaceorEthnicityInformation)  against the schema, it does succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, disable the Fallback Settings.

Then, double check the Agreement to make sure you correctly have the ISA11 set to the Repetition separator on the YOU->THEM tab.

Comment: Looking into the Fallback settings did help. The ISA11 in envelopes section of Fallback Settings did not have Repetition separator selected. Selecting Repetition separator and giving the right character there solved the problem, although I have to make sure now that agreement resolution works and I donot rely on fallback settings.